# How to write in one textField instead of all fields

Tags: java, swing

I'm developing a complex number calculator. I made 5 text fields, and when I click on a button to write a number it shows the text on all fields so it will be the same number on all fields.

This is the code of one button:

```java
JButton btn0 = new JButton("0");
btn0.setFont(new Font("Tahoma",Font.BOLD,15));
btn0.setBounds(199, 228, 80, 30);
frame.getContentPane().add(btn0);
btn0.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        String num = textField.getText() + btn0.getText();
        textField.setText(num);

        String num1 = field.getText() + btn0.getText();
        field.setText(num1);

        String num2 = field2.getText() + btn0.getText();
        field2.setText(num2);

        String num3 = field3.getText() + btn0.getText();
        field3.setText(num3);

        String num4 = field4.getText() + btn0.getText();
        field2.setText(num4);
    }
});
```

Comment: Why do you assign "num2" to 3 of your text fields?

Comment: i did copy paste so i forgot to change it

Comment: @AmroYasser Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] of your problem, which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: `when I click on a button to write a number it shows the text on all fields so it will be the same number on all fields.` - Assume all the text fields start with no text. So then you click a button and add the same text to all the text fields. So your code is doing exactly what you tell it to do. If you don't want it to do this, then don't assign the same text to every text field.

Answer (score 1):

When user clicks `btn0`, this `actionPerformed()` method you have mentioned here get executed. Inside this `actionPerformed()` method you are setting values of all text fields (`textField`, `field`, `field2` etc.). So, it is not surprising that text is set in all text fields.

Comment: What did you mean by "the field selected"? When user clicks the button, the focus will be on the button. Non of the text fields will be selected (focused). If you explain your objective, we might be able to help. May be you need to rethink about the high level design of your calculator.

Comment: i want when the user select the first field and when he clicks a button the text shows one the firrst field not all of them .

Comment: Can't you use only one text field in your calculator (like in usual calculators)? If you really need to have many text fields, then may be you can have a set of radio buttons (`JRadioButton`) to indicate which text field is "selected" at a given time. (A radio button for each text field.) Then you can use those radio buttons to decide which text field should be set.